# Mysql problemas con la recuperacion de datos select

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos, select

Tengo una bd localhost, y dos tablas en este caso son: cliente y venta, el atributo de la tabla cliente tiene una cadena extensa ejemplo "Juan Perez Salazar Diego", el problema surge cuando quiero recuperar los datos de la tabla cliente y venta, el codigo es el siguiente:

```
SELECT c.NOMBRE,c.EDAD,c.CELULAR, v.ZONA,v.PAGO,v.NENTRADA FROM cliente c ,venta v where c.ID = v.CLAVECL
```

El resultado es que solo recupera parte del atributo nombre. 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cuando la tabla cliente posee estos datos.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quiero recuperar toda la informacion del campo nombre, y no solo una parte
Gracias de antemano.

Psdt: Esta es la imagen de la columna expandida.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Algo tal vez tremendamente obvio, ¿ya trataste de expandir la columna, para checar si no quedaron ocultos los nombres?, pues no veo razón para que no los muestre

Comment: Si ya lo intente y nada

Comment: tu consulta la puedes mejorar borrando ese **where** y cambiando la por un **inner join**

Answer (score 1):

Posiblemente tengas activada la configuración para **Textos parciales**, verifica ésto presionando **Opciones** y selecciona **Textos completos** y posteriormente **Continuar**:

**+Opciones**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

**Textos completos**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero te funcione. Saludos ;)

Answer (score 0):

Imaginando que tu tabla venta contiene el id o algun dato referencial del cliente, podrias hacer la consulta usando INNER JOIN.
Por ejemplo:

```
SELECT c.nombre, c.edad, c.celular, v.zona, v.pago, v.nentrada 

FROM cliente c 

INNER JOIN venta v ON v.cliente = c.id // donde v.cliente seria el identificador de tu cliente

WHERE c.id = v.clavecl
```

Espero te ayude o al menos guiarte en la busqueda de la solucion a tu problema.

Comment: Pero el problema es que el nombre sale cortado, no como obtener los datos que finalmente aunque no es lo óptimo su consulta es correcta